# Navbar links with varying directory

Tags: html, directory, hyperlink

my directory is shaped like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npYmh.png)

in order to use my navbar between different html files, I made it into a seperate html file and use a placeholder to insert it where i need it. the problem is that now the links get thrown off.
for example: when im on the index file, the link `<a href="index.html"></a>` works without a problem. however, when im in the about_us file, the link `<a href="index.html"></a>` throws a cannot find in directory error because it would need `../` in front of the link.
any javascript I have also does not work for the nav.html.
any suggestions? is there a way to create links and start the directory from the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate to the correct HTML file, you have to pass the full path of the HTML file.

For eg: If your application is running in `https://localhost:8080` than you have to pass the full path as below:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/root/index.html">Home</a> 
<a href="http://localhost:8080/root/html-files/about_us.html">About Us</a>
```

Or if you directly opening the HTML file in your browser without any server, than pass the full path of your project folder as below:

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/.../your-project-name/root/index.html">Home</a> 
<a href="file:///C:/Users/.../your-project-name/root/html-files/about_us.html">About Us</a>
```

Note: Always use the file or folder name with a hyphen `-` or underscore `_`.

For eg: instead of `html files` rename your folder name as `html_files` or `html-files`.